# Memoir: Subbottom over several pages?

Tags: page-breaking, memoir, subfloats

In the Memoir class, I use the subbottom command to create subfigures, labeled, e.g., 1(a), 1(b), 1(c) etc. And this works very nicely. However, if I include more figures in subbottoms than what can be on one page, it does not put them on the next page - that is, it does not break the figure over several pages. I tried putting in a `\ContinuedFloat` at the beginning of the figure-environment, but then it is unable to compile.

I could of course just break the figure, but since the figures in the subbottoms belong together, I prefer to have them in the same figure and then labeled with consecutive letters.

Is there a way to obtain subbottoms that can be split over several pages when using the Memoir class?

The code could be something like shown below, where for instance the fourth subbottom is included on the same page as the three before, even though it does not fit onto this page.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{memoir}

\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\newsubfloat{figure}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb!]
\centering
\subbottom[Subcaption 1.]{\includegraphics[scale=0.27]{Picture1} \label{Fig:Subfig1.}} 
\subbottom[Subcaption 2.]{\includegraphics[scale=0.27]{Picture2} \label{Fig:Subfig2.}} 
\subbottom[Subcaption 3.]{\includegraphics[scale=0.27]{Picture3} \label{Fig:Subfig3.}} 
\subbottom[Subcaption 4.]{\includegraphics[scale=0.27]{Picture4} \label{Fig:Subfig4.}} 
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

a `figure`environment cannot have a pagebreak. Use the default environment `center` and set the float type:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{memoir}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\newsubfloat{figure}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\makeatletter\def\@captype{figure}\makeatother
\subbottom[Subcaption 1.]{\includegraphics[scale=0.27]{Picture1} \label{Fig:Subfig1.}} 
\subbottom[Subcaption 2.]{\includegraphics[scale=0.27]{Picture2} \label{Fig:Subfig2.}} 
\subbottom[Subcaption 3.]{\includegraphics[scale=0.27]{Picture3} \label{Fig:Subfig3.}} 
\subbottom[Subcaption 4.]{\includegraphics[scale=0.27]{Picture4} \label{Fig:Subfig4.}} 
\subbottom[Subcaption 1.]{\includegraphics[scale=0.27]{Picture1} \label{Fig:Subfig5.}} 
\subbottom[Subcaption 2.]{\includegraphics[scale=0.27]{Picture2} \label{Fig:Subfig6.}} 
\subbottom[Subcaption 3.]{\includegraphics[scale=0.27]{Picture3} \label{Fig:Subfig7.}} 
\subbottom[Subcaption 4.]{\includegraphics[scale=0.27]{Picture4} \label{Fig:Subfig8.}} 
\subbottom[Subcaption 1.]{\includegraphics[scale=0.27]{Picture1} \label{Fig:Subfig9.}} 
\subbottom[Subcaption 2.]{\includegraphics[scale=0.27]{Picture2} \label{Fig:Subfiga.}} 
\subbottom[Subcaption 3.]{\includegraphics[scale=0.27]{Picture3} \label{Fig:Subfigb.}} 
\subbottom[Subcaption 4.]{\includegraphics[scale=0.27]{Picture4} \label{Fig:Subfigc.}} 
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

you can also define a new environment `Figure`

```
\makeatletter 
\newenvironment{Figure}{\def\@captype{figure}\center}{\endcenter}
\makeatother
```

And then using this one instead of the environment `center` in my example without the float type setting.

Answer (score 7):

`\contsubbottom` might be useful

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\newsubfloat{figure}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb!]
\centering
\subbottom[Subcaption 1.]{\includegraphics[scale=0.27]{Picture1}%
        \label{Fig:Subfig1.}} 
\subbottom[Subcaption 2.]{\includegraphics[scale=0.27]{Picture2}% 
\label{Fig:Subfig2.}} 
\caption{Some intereting figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[htb!]
\centering
\contsubbottom[Subcaption 3.]{\includegraphics[scale=0.27]{Picture3}%
\label{Fig:Subfig3.}} 
\contsubbottom[Subcaption 4.]{\includegraphics[scale=0.27]{Picture4}%
\label{Fig:Subfig4.}} 
\contcaption{Concluded.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It would be great if you can show an example.

Comment: why should I do all the work, then people never learn to read the manual.

Comment: Just a suggestion :-) Thanks for the example though.